# Can I download files from inside folder (Sub files) dropbox python?

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

Hi I am getting all folders like this

```
 entries=dbx.files_list_folder('').entries
   print (entries[1].name)
   print (entries[2].name)
```

And unable to locate subfiles in these folders. As I searched on internet but till now no working function I found.

Comment: What do you get if you do this : 
`subentries=dbx.files_list_folder(entries[0].name).entries; print subentries[0]`

Comment: dropbox.stone_validators.ValidationError: 'ais-data' did not match pattern '(/(.|[\r\n])*)?|id:.*|(ns:[0-9]+(/.*)?)'        ,  ais-data is folder name @ChukUltima

Comment: That is failing because you need to supply the `path_lower`, not `name` when calling `files_list_folder`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

After listing entries using [`files_list_folder`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_list_folder) (and [`files_list_folder_continue`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_list_folder_continue)), you can check the type, and then download them if desired using [`files_download`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_download), like this:

```
entries = dbx.files_list_folder('').entries

for entry in entries:
    if isinstance(entry, dropbox.files.FileMetadata):  # this entry is a file
        md, res = dbx.files_download(entry.path_lower)
        print(md)  # this is the metadata for the downloaded file
        print(len(res.content))  # `res.content` contains the file data
```

Note that this code sample doesn't properly paginate using [`files_list_folder_continue`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_list_folder_continue) nor does it contain any error handling.

Comment: @F128115 That's the [`Metadata.path_lower`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.files.Metadata.path_lower) for the entry. It's the "lowercased full path in the user’s Dropbox."

Answer (score 0):

There is two possible way to do that:

Either you can write the content to the file or you can create a link (either redirected to the browser or just  get a downloadable link )

First way:

```
metadata, response = dbx.files_download(file_path+filename)
with open(metadata.name, "wb") as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Second way:

```
link = dbx.sharing_create_shared_link(file_path+filename)
print(link.url)
```

if you want link to be downloadable then replace `0` with `1`:

`path = link.url.replace("0", "1")`